# using gitosis for GIT

Tags: git, gitosis

I want user A and B to have clone, push and pull while user C can only do clone and pull (no push)

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-dameon` is used for public access. But you can use gitosis to grant read-only access to a particular group of users. For instance:

```
[group thegood]
writable = myRepo
members = A B
[group thebad]
readonly = myRepo
members = C
[repo myRepo]
description = "my project"
```

See [example.conf](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=blob;f=example.conf;hb=master) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Gitosis can't limit write access to repository. If user is in `members` list then it has all read/commit rights.

[Original documentation](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) mentions that in such case just setup a `git-daemon` instance to repositories:

```
sudo -u git git-daemon --base-path=/home/git/repositories/ --export-all
```